# confused about API call. Calculating time butween current date and future date

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a project for a course that needs to make several API calls in a row.  I've made the first and prepared the second but I'm confused about what the API is asking for.  I'm trying to use the dark sky API to get the weather for a future date.  I have a form where the user submits the future date in the format of MM/DD/YYYY and I have split that up into three variables: month, day, year.  The problem is that I'm not sure what the time parameter is asking for.  Because of this, I'm getting a 'Poorly formated request' error.  Specifically I'm using the dark sky time machine request API.  The page for it is here:

https://darksky.net/dev/docs#time-machine-request

could someone take a look and tell me what exactly it's asking for for the time parameter?

It looks like it may be asking for the amount of seconds between now and the future date. How would I calculate that?

The other option is to use the date format but I'm confused about how to format it.  The current fetch request I have looks like this:

```
const res = await fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${darksky_key}/${lat},${lng},${year}-${month}-${day}`)
```

Could someone take a look at that API and the time parameter and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  And if I need to calculate the time from one date to a future date, how do I do that?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says time has to be in UNIX format,

```
const time = new Date(`${year}.${month}.${day}`).getTime() / 1000
const res = await fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${darksky_key}/${lat},${lng},${time}`)
```

Comment: if you found this answer helpful, please click on vote up.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the amount of seconds between now and future data, it is the UNIX time in seconds:

> **time** required
>
> Either be a UNIX time (that is, seconds since midnight GMT on 1 Jan 1970) or a string formatted as follows: `[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[HH]:[MM]:[SS][timezone]`. `timezone` should either be omitted (to refer to local time for the location being requested), `Z` (referring to GMT time), or `+[HH][MM]` or `-[HH][MM]` for an offset from GMT in hours and minutes. The timezone is only used for determining the time of the request; the response will always be relative to the local time zone.

What you need is to convert the given date to its unix timestamp representation.

Or you should fix your date param to match the format:

```
const res = await fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${darksky_key}/${lat},${lng},${year}-${month}-${day}T00:00:00Z`)
```